# Method to filter an array

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on an implementation in angular to look into an array a bring the value according to the name of the definition.

```
let definitions = [
{
  definitionsTest1: [
    {
      headerName: 'Status',
      field: 'status',
      filter: true,
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Name',
      field: 'name',
      filter: true,
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Project',
      field: 'project',
      filter: true,
      sortable: true
    }
  ]
},
{
  definitionsTest2: [
    {
      headerName: 'Status',
      field: 'status',
      filter: true,
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Name',
      field: 'name',
      filter: true,
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Project',
      field: 'project',
      filter: true,
      sortable: true
    }
  ]
}
]
```

I'm doing the array, so I can change it. But the idea I'm thinking is to `find` but since they have different names I can't put something like this

```
return definitions.find(x => x === 'definitionsTest2')
```

Or at least I'm not sure, how could I apply the `find` method there.

Could you help me or give some ideas about how should I change the array or what could I do?

**Note** 
I can change the array or put new things on it, but the `names` (definitionsTest1 and definitionsTest2) should be there.

Comment: This `return definitions.find(x => x === 'definitionsTest2')` is the same than `definitions.definitionsTest2`. I don't understand which is the problem. The name of the definitionsTests are variables in your object definitions.

Comment: @Pauho I tried to do it that way, just put `definitions.definitionsTest2` and it gives me an error `Property 'definitionsTest2' does not exist`

Comment: A simple way : `definitions.find(x => console.log(Object.keys(x).toString() === 'definitionsTest2'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if each definition object has a property assigned, you don't need an array. The `definitions` array can be an object. Something like this:

```
let definitions = {
   definitionsTest1: {...},
   definitionsTest2: {...},
   ...
};
```

You can get the keys of the initial object and see if the desired key exists.

To get the keys simply use `Object.keys()`:

```
let keys = Object.keys(definitions);
```

Then search for the desired key:

```
let key = '...';
let result;

if (keys.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
    result = definitions[key];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the object keys includes the key you're looking for like so:

```
return definitions.find(x => Object.keys(x).includes('definitionsTest2'))
```